# How can i make customized Business Plans WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Limitation for users are not applied successfully .

I create API then i create customized Business Plans limitation 1 Request Per Day .
the API keep responding more than one time in day which is wrong .

- note that the deploy in 3 servers and i call servers throw load balancer

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured three all-in-one API Manager instances and load-balanced them? If yes, then you will have to configure the Traffic Manager instances inside the API Manager to communicate with each other to throttle the requests.

The Traffic Manager component in the WSO2 API Manager is used to block and throttle the requests based on the plans that the particular API is subscribed to. But, please note that there is a chance of at least one request passing through above the mentioned limit due to the asynchronous nature of throttling architecture in the WSO2 API Manager.

If you have configured three all-in-one API Managers without any inter-communication between the Traffic Manager components, then you might see at least 4 requests getting served by the instances as they are load-balanced (considering round-robin).